# Eigen3/C++: MatrixXd multiply one row with another

Tags: c++, matrix, linear-algebra, eigen3

Using the Eigen3/C++ Library, given a `MatrixXd`

```
    / x0   ...  y0  \
    | x1   ...  y1  |
M = | ...  ...  ... |
    |               |
    \ xN   ...  yN  /
```

what is the fasted method to achieve a modified version as shown below?

```
     / x0 * y0   ...  y0  \
     | x1 * y1   ...  y1  |
M' = | ...  ...  ...      |
     |                    |
     \ xN * yN   ...  yN  /
```

That is, one column (the one with the x-s) is replaced by itself 
multiplied with another column (that with the y-s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you mean how to coefficient-wise assign-multiply the first and last column vectors ? there are many ways of doing it, but the easiest/fastest might be

```
Eigen::MatrixXd M2 = M;

M2.leftCols<1>().array() *= M2.rightCols<1>().array();
```

an alternative might be constructing an uninitialized matrix with a given number of rows/cols and then block-assign like

```
Eigen::MatrixXd M2{ M.rows(), M.cols() };

M2.rightCols( M.cols() - 1 ) = M.rightCols( M.cols() - 1 );
M2.leftCols<1>() = M.leftCols<1>().cwiseProduct( M.rightCols<1>() );
```

which is faster I don't know ( but your preferred profiler does ).

for future questions, here is the official [Eigen quick reference](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__QuickRefPage.html) ;)

Comment: I ended up using the '.block()' functions which allowed me to address arbitrary colums, but the idea you gave was the hint to the solution.